# Laravel: SQL update current time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

First Laravel Project. I have a controller, where I upload an image and edit two cell in a mysql row (img and current time) then return to ProductDetails page.

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request, $id){
    $file = $request->file('image');
    //Display File Name
    echo 'File Name: '.$file->getClientOriginalName();
    echo '<br>';
    //Display File Extension
    echo 'File Extension: '.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    echo '<br>';
    //Display File Real Path
    echo 'File Real Path: '.$file->getRealPath();
    echo '<br>';
    //Display File Size
    echo 'File Size: '.$file->getSize();
    echo '<br>';
    //Display File Mime Type
    echo 'File Mime Type: '.$file->getMimeType();
    //Move Uploaded File
    $destinationPath = 'media/productimg';
    $file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());
    $img=$file->getClientOriginalName();
    DB::update('update inventory set img = ? lastchange = ? where barcode = ?',[$img,CURRENT_TIME(),$id]);
    $product = DB::select('select * FROM inventory WHERE barcode = ?', [$id]);
    return view('productdetails',['product'=>$product]);
    }
```

My problem is that Laravel don't understand the "CURRENT_TIME()"

> FatalThrowableError in InventoryController.php line 47: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\CURRENT_TIME()

Do I need additional dependency or Laravel has a built-in method for that? (I have to use it on several places)

**EDIT:** lastchange is a DATETIME cell

Comment: I guess it's better to remove your exceed code from the question and leave only the DB query related code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel uses [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). 
to get the current time just do this

**import the namespace:**
 `use Carbon\Carbon;`

**Create the variable:** `$now = Carbon::now();`

and now your query should look like this:

```
DB::update('update inventory set img = ? lastchange = ? where barcode = ?',[$img,$now,$id]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) The site needs 9 more minutes to accept your answer

Comment: @Feralheart glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

nicaolas's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42553420/2359679) seems to be good solution but as another approach is to use mysql internal [now()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function or it's [alternatives](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
DB::update('update inventory set img = ? lastchange = NOW() where barcode = ?',[$img,$id]);
```

Comment: Your code would not work because of too much params for two placeholders. Correct version: `DB::update('update inventory set img = ? lastchange = NOW() where barcode = ?',[$img,$id]);`